# Pushing read-only GUI properties back into ViewModel

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, readonly

I want to write a ViewModel that always knows the current state of some read-only dependency properties from the View.

Specifically, my GUI contains a FlowDocumentPageViewer, which displays one page at a time from a FlowDocument. FlowDocumentPageViewer exposes two read-only dependency properties called CanGoToPreviousPage and CanGoToNextPage. I want my ViewModel to always know the values of these two View properties.

I figured I could do this with a OneWayToSource databinding:

```
<FlowDocumentPageViewer
    CanGoToNextPage="{Binding NextPageAvailable, Mode=OneWayToSource}" ...>
```

If this was allowed, it would be perfect: whenever the FlowDocumentPageViewer's CanGoToNextPage property changed, the new value would get pushed down into the ViewModel's NextPageAvailable property, which is exactly what I want.

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile: I get an error saying **'CanGoToPreviousPage' property is read-only and cannot be set from markup.** Apparently read-only properties don't support *any* kind of databinding, not even databinding that's read-only with respect to that property.

I could make my ViewModel's properties be DependencyProperties, and make a OneWay binding going the other way, but I'm not crazy about the separation-of-concerns violation (ViewModel would need a reference to the View, which MVVM databinding is supposed to avoid).

FlowDocumentPageViewer doesn't expose a CanGoToNextPageChanged event, and I don't know of any good way to get change notifications from a DependencyProperty, short of creating another DependencyProperty to bind it to, which seems like overkill here.

How can I keep my ViewModel informed of changes to the view's read-only properties?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Yes, I've done this in the past with the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties, both of which are read-only. I created an attached behavior that has `ObservedWidth` and `ObservedHeight` attached properties. It also has an `Observe` property that is used to do the initial hook-up. Usage looks like this:

```xml
<UserControl ...
    SizeObserver.Observe="True"
    SizeObserver.ObservedWidth="{Binding Width, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
    SizeObserver.ObservedHeight="{Binding Height, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

So the view model has `Width` and `Height` properties that are always in sync with the `ObservedWidth` and `ObservedHeight` attached properties. The `Observe` property simply attaches to the `SizeChanged` event of the `FrameworkElement`. In the handle, it updates its `ObservedWidth` and `ObservedHeight` properties. Ergo, the `Width` and `Height` of the view model is always in sync with the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the `UserControl`.

Perhaps not the perfect solution (I agree - read-only DPs *should* support `OneWayToSource` bindings), but it works and it upholds the MVVM pattern. Obviously, the `ObservedWidth` and `ObservedHeight` DPs are *not* read-only.

UPDATE: here's code that implements the functionality described above:

```cs
public static class SizeObserver
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObserveProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Observe",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(SizeObserver),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnObserveChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObservedWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ObservedWidth",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(SizeObserver));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObservedHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ObservedHeight",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(SizeObserver));

    public static bool GetObserve(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        return (bool)frameworkElement.GetValue(ObserveProperty);
    }

    public static void SetObserve(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, bool observe)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        frameworkElement.SetValue(ObserveProperty, observe);
    }

    public static double GetObservedWidth(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        return (double)frameworkElement.GetValue(ObservedWidthProperty);
    }

    public static void SetObservedWidth(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, double observedWidth)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        frameworkElement.SetValue(ObservedWidthProperty, observedWidth);
    }

    public static double GetObservedHeight(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        return (double)frameworkElement.GetValue(ObservedHeightProperty);
    }

    public static void SetObservedHeight(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, double observedHeight)
    {
        frameworkElement.AssertNotNull("frameworkElement");
        frameworkElement.SetValue(ObservedHeightProperty, observedHeight);
    }

    private static void OnObserveChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)dependencyObject;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            frameworkElement.SizeChanged += OnFrameworkElementSizeChanged;
            UpdateObservedSizesForFrameworkElement(frameworkElement);
        }
        else
        {
            frameworkElement.SizeChanged -= OnFrameworkElementSizeChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void OnFrameworkElementSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateObservedSizesForFrameworkElement((FrameworkElement)sender);
    }

    private static void UpdateObservedSizesForFrameworkElement(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        // WPF 4.0 onwards
        frameworkElement.SetCurrentValue(ObservedWidthProperty, frameworkElement.ActualWidth);
        frameworkElement.SetCurrentValue(ObservedHeightProperty, frameworkElement.ActualHeight);

        // WPF 3.5 and prior
        ////SetObservedWidth(frameworkElement, frameworkElement.ActualWidth);
        ////SetObservedHeight(frameworkElement, frameworkElement.ActualHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you could do some trickery to automatically attach the properties, without needing Observe. But this looks like a fine solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Kent.  I posted a code sample below for this "SizeObserver" class.

Comment: +1 to this sentiment: "read-only DPs should support OneWayToSource bindings"

Comment: Perhaps even better to create just one `Size` property, combining Heigth and Width. Approx. 50% less code.

Comment: @Gerard: That won't work because there is no `ActualSize` property in `FrameworkElement`. If you want direct binding of the attached properties, you must create two properties to be bound to `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` respectively.

Comment: Cannot be used directly on UserControl.

Answer (score 65):

I use a universal solution which works not only with ActualWidth and ActualHeight, but also with any data you can bind to at least in reading mode.

The markup looks like this, provided ViewportWidth and ViewportHeight are properties of the view model

```
<Canvas>
    <u:DataPiping.DataPipes>
         <u:DataPipeCollection>
             <u:DataPipe Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                         Target="{Binding Path=ViewportWidth, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
             <u:DataPipe Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                         Target="{Binding Path=ViewportHeight, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
          </u:DataPipeCollection>
     </u:DataPiping.DataPipes>
<Canvas>
```

Here is the source code for the custom elements

```cs
public class DataPiping
{
    #region DataPipes (Attached DependencyProperty)

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataPipesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DataPipes",
        typeof(DataPipeCollection),
        typeof(DataPiping),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static void SetDataPipes(DependencyObject o, DataPipeCollection value)
    {
        o.SetValue(DataPipesProperty, value);
    }

    public static DataPipeCollection GetDataPipes(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return (DataPipeCollection)o.GetValue(DataPipesProperty);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class DataPipeCollection : FreezableCollection<DataPipe>
{

}

public class DataPipe : Freezable
{
    #region Source (DependencyProperty)

    public object Source
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(object), typeof(DataPipe),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSourceChanged)));

    private static void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((DataPipe)d).OnSourceChanged(e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnSourceChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Target = e.NewValue;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Target (DependencyProperty)

    public object Target
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(TargetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TargetProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Target", typeof(object), typeof(DataPipe),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new DataPipe();
    }
}
```

Comment: (via an answer from user543564): This is not an answer but a comment to Dmitry - I used your solution and it worked great. Nice universal solution that can be used generically in different places. I used it to push some ui element properties (ActualHeight and ActualWidth) in to my viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me bind to a normal get only property.  Unfortunately the property didn't publish INotifyPropertyChanged events.  I solved this by assigning a name to the DataPipe binding and adding the following to the controls changed event:  BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(bindingName, DataPipe.SourceProperty).UpdateTarget();

Comment: This solution worked well for me. My only tweak was setting BindsTwoWayByDefault to true for the FrameworkPropertyMetadata on the TargetProperty DependencyProperty.

Comment: The only gripe about this solution seems to be that it breaks clean encapsulation, as the `Target` property has to be made writeable even though it must not be changed from the outside :-/

Comment: For those who would prefer NuGet package over copy-n-pasting the code: I've added DataPipe to my opensource JungleControls library. See [DataPipe documentation](http://blog.angeloflogic.com/2014/12/datapipe-pushing-read-only-dependency.html).

Comment: Worked immediately - thank you very much. Is there a repository where this code is/can be maintained (not that there's much to it!)

Answer (score 20):

If anyone else is interested, I coded up an approximation of Kent's solution here:

```cs
class SizeObserver
{
    #region " Observe "

    public static bool GetObserve(FrameworkElement elem)
    {
        return (bool)elem.GetValue(ObserveProperty);
    }

    public static void SetObserve(
      FrameworkElement elem, bool value)
    {
        elem.SetValue(ObserveProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObserveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Observe", typeof(bool), typeof(SizeObserver),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnObserveChanged));

    static void OnObserveChanged(
      DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement elem = depObj as FrameworkElement;
        if (elem == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            elem.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
        else
            elem.SizeChanged -= OnSizeChanged;
    }

    static void OnSizeChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, e.OriginalSource))
            return;

        FrameworkElement elem = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
        if (elem != null)
        {
            SetObservedWidth(elem, elem.ActualWidth);
            SetObservedHeight(elem, elem.ActualHeight);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region " ObservedWidth "

    public static double GetObservedWidth(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(ObservedWidthProperty);
    }

    public static void SetObservedWidth(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ObservedWidthProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ObservedWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObservedWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ObservedWidth", typeof(double), typeof(SizeObserver), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));

    #endregion

    #region " ObservedHeight "

    public static double GetObservedHeight(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(ObservedHeightProperty);
    }

    public static void SetObservedHeight(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ObservedHeightProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ObservedHeight.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObservedHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ObservedHeight", typeof(double), typeof(SizeObserver), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));

    #endregion
}
```

Feel free to use it in your apps.  It works well.  (Thanks Kent!)

Answer (score 10):

Here is another solution to this "bug" which I blogged about here:
[OneWayToSource Binding for ReadOnly Dependency Property](http://meleak.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/onewaytosource-binding-for-readonly-dependency-property/)

It works by using two Dependency Properties, Listener and Mirror. Listener is bound OneWay to the TargetProperty and in the PropertyChangedCallback it updates the Mirror property which is bound OneWayToSource to whatever was specified in the Binding. I call it `PushBinding` and it can be set on any read-only Dependency Property like this

```
<TextBlock Name="myTextBlock"
           Background="LightBlue">
    <pb:PushBindingManager.PushBindings>
        <pb:PushBinding TargetProperty="ActualHeight" Path="Height"/>
        <pb:PushBinding TargetProperty="ActualWidth" Path="Width"/>
    </pb:PushBindingManager.PushBindings>
</TextBlock>
```

[Download Demo Project Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqkmsp0q7hb568z/PushBindingInStyleDemo.zip?dl=0).
It contains source code and short sample usage.

*One last note, since .NET 4.0 we are even further away from built-in-support for this, since a [OneWayToSource Binding reads the value back from the Source after it has updated it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875751/onewaytosource-binding-seems-broken-in-net-4-0)*

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow should be entirely self-contained. It's fine to include a link to optional external references, but all code required for the answer should be included in the answer itself. Please update your question so that it can be used without visiting any other web site.

Comment: That looks like self advertising to your blog rather than an answer.

Comment: Yeah I guess you are both right, it does look kind of advertising even though that wasn't mine intent. After I made that blog post I just answered all the questions which was about OneWayToSource Binding for readonly properties. I'm not really sure what else to add to the answer though, it contains sample code of how to do it and a link to the demo-project which isn't on my blog. I'll clean it up a bit :-)

Answer (score 5):

I like Dmitry Tashkinov's solution! 
However it crashed my VS in design mode. That's why I added a line to OnSourceChanged method:

```
    private static void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!((bool)DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject)).DefaultValue))
            ((DataPipe)d).OnSourceChanged(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done a bit simpler:

xaml:

```
behavior:ReadOnlyPropertyToModelBindingBehavior.ReadOnlyDependencyProperty="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
behavior:ReadOnlyPropertyToModelBindingBehavior.ModelProperty="{Binding MyViewModelProperty}"
```

cs:

```cs
public class ReadOnlyPropertyToModelBindingBehavior
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ReadOnlyDependencyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
     "ReadOnlyDependencyProperty", 
     typeof(object), 
     typeof(ReadOnlyPropertyToModelBindingBehavior),
     new PropertyMetadata(OnReadOnlyDependencyPropertyPropertyChanged));

  public static void SetReadOnlyDependencyProperty(DependencyObject element, object value)
  {
     element.SetValue(ReadOnlyDependencyPropertyProperty, value);
  }

  public static object GetReadOnlyDependencyProperty(DependencyObject element)
  {
     return element.GetValue(ReadOnlyDependencyPropertyProperty);
  }

  private static void OnReadOnlyDependencyPropertyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     SetModelProperty(obj, e.NewValue);
  }


  public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
     "ModelProperty", 
     typeof(object), 
     typeof(ReadOnlyPropertyToModelBindingBehavior), 
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

  public static void SetModelProperty(DependencyObject element, object value)
  {
     element.SetValue(ModelPropertyProperty, value);
  }

  public static object GetModelProperty(DependencyObject element)
  {
     return element.GetValue(ModelPropertyProperty);
  }
}
```

Comment: May be a bit simpler, but if I read it well, it allows **only one** such binding on the Element. I mean, I think that with this approach, you won't be able to bind both ActualWidth **and** ActualHeight. Just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @eriksmith200's idea - It can be done much more simply with `Behavior`, without a limit on the number of properties, below is an example on `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth`:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp21.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Behaviors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp21"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="378"
        Height="293"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:Model}"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ReadOnlyPropertyToModelBindingBehavior ModelProperty="{Binding Height}" ReadOnlyDependencyProperty="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
        <local:ReadOnlyPropertyToModelBindingBehavior ModelProperty="{Binding Width}" ReadOnlyDependencyProperty="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
    </Behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Margin="35,38,0,0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Text="{Binding Height}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap">
            
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Margin="35,103,0,0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Text="{Binding Width}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp21
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new Model();
        }
    }

    public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private double _Height;
        public double Height
        {
            get { return _Height; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _Height) return;
                _Height = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Height));
            }
        }

        private double _Width;
        public double Width
        {
            get { return _Width; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _Width) return;
                _Width = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Width));
            }
        }
    }

    public class ReadOnlyPropertyToModelBindingBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
    {
        public object ReadOnlyDependencyProperty
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ReadOnlyDependencyPropertyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ReadOnlyDependencyPropertyProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ReadOnlyDependencyPropertyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ReadOnlyDependencyProperty", typeof(object), typeof(ReadOnlyPropertyToModelBindingBehavior),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnReadOnlyDependencyPropertyPropertyChanged));

        public object ModelProperty
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(ModelPropertyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ModelPropertyProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelPropertyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ModelProperty", typeof(object), typeof(ReadOnlyPropertyToModelBindingBehavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

        private static void OnReadOnlyDependencyPropertyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var b = obj as ReadOnlyPropertyToModelBindingBehavior;
            b.ModelProperty = e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]