# Bind to ActualHeight of Item ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, itemscontrol, actualheight

I have two separate `ItemsControl`s that appear side by side.  The `ItemsControl`s bind to the same `ItemsSource`, but they display the data differently.

Each item displayed on the left will most likely be smaller than the same item on the right. This causes a problem because the rows will not line up, so I need the item on the left to bind to the item on the right.

```
ItemsControl        ItemsControl
|Item 1         |Item 1
|Item 2         |Item 2
|Item 3         |
|Item 4         |Item 3
```

As you can see, Item 2 on the right is larger, so it throws off the alignment.  So if I can bind left's Item 2 to right's Item 2's `ActualHeight` the problem would be solved.  How can I do this in XAML?

**Edit:** To make things more complicated, the `ItemsControl` on the right needs to scroll right to left, but both `ItemsControls` need to scroll up and down together.  Basically, the left one provides a header of sorts for the items on the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on *Jobi Joy's* answer

You can't do a direct `OneWayToSource` Binding in Xaml for the ReadOnly Dependency Property ActualHeight but there are many workarounds. The answer by *Kent Boogaart* in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083224/pushing-read-only-gui-properties-back-into-viewmodel) is my favorite. What is does is that it uses an Attached Behavior that listens to the `SizeChanged` event of any `FrameworkElement` and updates two Attached Properties, Width and Height, accordingly.

With a `TextBlock` for example, `ActualHeight` can be used to push into a Height property of the ViewModel like

```
<TextBlock local:ActualSizeBehavior.ObserveActualSize="True"
           local:ActualSizeBehavior.ActualHeight="{Binding Path=Height,
                                                           Mode=OneWayToSource}"
           .../>
```

---

**Synkronize two ScrollViewers**
You can either use a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` to listen for changes in the `VerticalOffsetProperty` property or subscribe to the `ScrollChanged` event and call `ScrollToVerticalOffset`. Example

**Xaml**

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewerLeft"
              ScrollChanged="scrollViewerLeft_ScrollChanged">
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewerRight"
              ScrollChanged="scrollViewerRight_ScrollChanged">
```

**Code behind event handlers**

```
private void scrollViewerLeft_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewerRight.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewerLeft.VerticalOffset);
}
private void scrollViewerRight_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewerLeft.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewerRight.VerticalOffset);
}
```

**ActualSizeBehavior**

```
public static class ActualSizeBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ActualSize",
                                            typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(ActualSizeBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnActualSizeChanged));
    public static bool GetActualSize(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ActualSizeProperty);
    }
    public static void SetActualSize(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ActualSizeProperty, value);
    }
    private static void OnActualSizeChanged(DependencyObject dpo,
                                            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = dpo as FrameworkElement;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
        {
            element.SizeChanged += element_SizeChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            element.SizeChanged -= element_SizeChanged;
        }
    }

    static void element_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
        SetActualWidth(element, element.ActualWidth);
        SetActualHeight(element, element.ActualHeight);
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty ActualWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ActualWidth", typeof(double), typeof(ActualSizeBehavior));
    public static void SetActualWidth(DependencyObject element, double value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ActualWidthProperty, value);
    }
    public static double GetActualWidth(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (double)element.GetValue(ActualWidthProperty);
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty ActualHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ActualHeight", typeof(double), typeof(ActualSizeBehavior));
    public static void SetActualHeight(DependencyObject element, double value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ActualHeightProperty, value);
    }
    public static double GetActualHeight(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (double)element.GetValue(ActualHeightProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked for me.  However, I have my reservations as to whether storing view specific data in the view model upholds MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `ItemsSource` is same on both, you can use a single `ItemsControl` and a whole row represented as two sections (Two columns of a Grid) inside that single `DataTemplate`, then heights will get aligned automatically. You can always style it to look like it is part of two different `ItemsControl` but technically one.

Another way to go with this is, adding a Height property in to the ViewModel (*of course not very right design since adding View dependency to VM*). TwoWay bind the height to the ActualHeight of the left-itemsControl ItemContainerStyle. And on the right-itemscontrol bind that Height property to the Height of ItemsContainerStyle {One Way}. So both will be in sync.

Another idea based on your update 'Need of the scroll on the right side' : 
   Use a single ListView and have two columns in it, and of those two GridViewColumn.CellTemplate have your two DataTemplates. This idea still needs column freezing on the first column. But that may be more tricky.

Anyway I would go with the first approach here.

Comment: Unfortunately, the two column grid won't work because of the scrolling scenario I have (see my updated question).

The actual height in the ViewModel might work, but I'm not sure if that should be something that goes in the ViewModel since it is View specific.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to perform binding to the ActualHeight, so I couldn't complete option one or two.  I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BindingHub.aspx

That's how you can bind to Read-Only Dependency Properties using BindingHub:

```
<bindings:BindingHub 
       Visibility="Hidden"
       Socket1="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Item, Mode=OneWay}"
       Socket2="{Binding ItemWidth, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
       Connect="(1 in, 2 out)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this exact problem. I used the read only binding solution found here:
https://meleak.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/onewaytosource-binding-for-readonly-dependency-property/

Using this I was able to bind the read only `ActualHeight` of each `ListViewItem` in one `ListView` to a property in my item view model called `ListViewItemHeight`. Then, in the second `ListView`, I bound the height of each item to `ListViewItemHeight`.