# How To Get A Rectangle With Layout Calculated From A Unit Test?

Tags: wpf, unit-testing

I'm out to write some attached properties as suggested in [Pushing read-only GUI properties back into ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083224/pushing-read-only-gui-properties-back-into-viewmodel)

I've written the following unit test:

```
    private const double Dimension = 10.0;

    [Test]
    [RequiresSTA]
    public void Gets_ActualWidth()
    {
        var rectangle = new Rectangle() { Width = Dimension, Height = Dimension };
        double actualWidthMeasurement = Measurements.GetActualWidth(rectangle);
        Assert.That(actualWidthMeasurement, Is.EqualTo(Dimension));
    }
```

This is too naive though, the rectangle has an ActualWidth of 0 because no layout has been calculated.

Is there a simple way I can get a Rectangle with it's layout calculated.

I tried adding it to a StackPanel and calling Arrange(new Rect(0,0,20,20)), but still got a rectangle with ActualWidth/ActualHeight = 0.0d.

---

**SOLUTION**

```
    [Test]
    [RequiresSTA]
    public void Gets_ActualWidth()
    {
        var rectangle = new Rectangle() { Width = Dimension, Height = Dimension};
        rectangle.Measure(new Size(20, 20));
        rectangle.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 20, 20));
        double actualWidthMeasurement = Measurements.GetActualWidth(rectangle);
        Assert.That(actualWidthMeasurement, Is.EqualTo(Dimension));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see that you called Measure.  That should be called before Arrange or else the Arrange will fail as everything has a DesiredSize of 0,0.

```
myStackPanel.Measure(new Size(20, 20));
myStackPanel.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 20, 20));
```

Comment: That's great, thanks, I don't need the StackPanel either, see my edit for a working unit test.

Comment: True for this case.  Some objects do need to be added to a parent, though (e.g., if you want to make sure a template gets applied).