# Obtain a size of UIElement after the initialisation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, uielement

I am trying to develop a program that has the possibility to adapt at the screen resolution of the user.

I am using mvvm with the pushbinding of Meleak to obtain the actual size of my MainWindow:

[Getting Window Properties in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653566/getting-window-properties-in-viewmodel)

For positioning my object, I am using `GridRow` and `GridColumn`.  Now I am trying to optimize this size, for that I have the need to get the `ActualSize` of my other `UIElment`, but like their size depend of their contents, I don't know how I can get their size, I try with a binding onewaytosource but I obtain a size of 0.0 and obviously is not the size after initialisation.

Comment: I have edited your question to what I think you were trying to say, I think you will need to add more details though.

Comment: Yes i post this question a bit too fast, sorry for that.

Comment: @Gat: You have any sample code for what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Meleak : I make you a quick sample

Comment: @Meleak : you can find an example here : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5Iv6R2fQq3UV1JJZ09iNlBNTm8/edit?pli=1

Comment: @Meleak just remove .doc, else in this example is a border(in my project it is datagrid) that has this size depend of listbox, but if you resize the mywindow,you can see it has inifiny size.

Answer (score 0):

The event `Loaded` can be used to measure the `ActualHeight` of a visual object.

If this is used on the window as below, the internal content should all be rendered and be available for you to reference.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var temp = this.ActualHeight;
}
```

In this example I am finding the window's `ActualHeight` but you can use it for any object within the window.

If you have nested windows/views the `Loaded` event is available on them as well.