# Binding to TextBlock Width property in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `TextBlock` control in my view, its `Width` depends on the `Text` property.

I'm looking for some way to bind the TextBlocks `Width` to a property in my model,which will work as follows:

1. The setting of the `Width` must be done automatically based on `Text`
2. In my button click I would like to retrieve the Width

I've tried the code below, but it keeps the `Width` as 0 if I don't explicitly set it in the constructor of the view model.Tried `Mode=OneWayToSource` and `Mode=OneWay` but it made no difference, any suggestions?

**View:**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Some text" Width="{Binding TextWidth,Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    <Button Content="Show Width" Height="30" Width="90" Command="{Binding ShowTextWidth}" />
</Grid>
```

**View model:**

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

private DelegateCommand<object> showTextWidth;
public DelegateCommand<object> ShowTextWidth
{
    get { return showTextWidth; }
    set { showTextWidth = value; }
}

private double textWidth;
public double TextWidth
{
    get { return textWidth; }
    set 
    { 
        textWidth = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TextWidth");
    }
}

public ViewModel()
{
    //If I explicitly specify the width it works:
    //TextWidth = 100;
    ShowTextWidth = new DelegateCommand<object>(ShowWidth);
}

private void ShowWidth(object parameter)
{
    MessageBox.Show(TextWidth.ToString());
}
```

}

Comment: Is this just for the purposes of layout?  Or is there some reason you really need to explicitly set the width?  If for layout, you're better off relaying on "Auto" width spec.

Comment: I don't need to set the width it must auto size based on Text, I just want to be able to access the width from the view model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up creating an attached behavior [by Maleak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653566/getting-window-properties-in-viewmodel) which was inspired by Kent Boogaarts [Pushing read-only GUI properties back into ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083224/pushing-read-only-gui-properties-back-into-viewmodel), can't believe it's so complicated to push the value of ActualWidth into the view model!

Answer (score 1):

Width is a DependencyProperty on TextBlock. In this case it's a Target for Binding and TextWidth is your source for Binding. OneWayToSource seems like the way to go, you are setting TextWidth to 100 in the ViewModel which does not propogate to Width on TextBlock because it's OneWayToSource yes correct, Width (Target) is then setting TextWidth (Source) to Double.NaN because of OneWayToSource and that's why you're seeing 0...

ActualWidth should work like sa_ddam213 said but also consider that your TextBlock doesn't grow in Width (ActualWidth) when the Text changes because it is spanning the total width of your Grid layout. Either put it in a ColumnDefinition with Width set to Auto or make your HorizontalAlignment Left to see the ActualWidth change when the Text changes.

I have made some changes to your source code. Consider using CommandParameter on your button? Check out the link...

[WpfApplication10.zip](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-KhmdyEQF-0bi0xYVRNcWp1eDg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

you dont really need to set the Width if you choose a layout panel wich can handle this for you.

eg. a columndefinition with width=auto grows with your text

Comment: I need the Width to do size calculations, the example in my question is just for simplicity

Comment: you wrote the width must auto size based on text. wpf layoutcontainer can handle this. so i dont know why you wanna calc some with. btw you should retrieve ActualWidth if you wanna know the acutal width.

Answer (score 0):

To set the Width depending on its containing Text you could bind the Width-Property to the Text-Property and use a converter like so:

```
<TextBlock Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToWidth}}"
```

Your converter could look like:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = value.ToString();
tb.Measure(new Size(int.MaxValue, 20)); //20 if there shouldnt be a linebreak
return tb.DesiredSize.Width;
```

Comment: The Width should be set automatically based on Text, I just need some way to access the TextBlock Width using properties in my view model as i need to do some additional calculations based on this size

Comment: In my example the Width is automatically set based on Text. If you need to do additional calculations, why dont you do these in your converter?

Comment: I need to do these calculations in the view model, that's why it should ideally be a property