# How can I find UIElements in a rectangle in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, rectangles, uielement

I need to  find `UIElement`s in (rectangle/area/bounds).

MainWindow I'm doing the following:

- I register the mouse down as the start position.
- I regsiter the mouse up position.
- Now I need to find ll (buttons, textboxes, etc) in the rectangle between start
   postion and the end  position.

I found in the msdn the `HitTest` approach but it is only for one point.  I think, walking through all points in the founded 
rectangle it is a performance disaster.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx

My code based on MVVM pattern:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<UIElementViewModel> wells;   
private Point stratPoint; // Mouse down
public ICommand MouseUpRightCommand
{
  get
  {
    if (this.mouseUpRightCommand == null)
    {
      this.mouseUpRightCommand = new RelayCommands(
        param =>
       {
          if (param is MouseButtonEventArgs)
          {
            var e = (param as MouseButtonEventArgs);

            //Set the end point
            endPosition = e.GetPosition(((ItemsControl)e.Source));

            // for example, here I want to find all controls(UIElements) in the
            // founded rectangle of stratPoint and endPosition.

          }
        });
    }

    return this.mouseUpRightCommand;
  }
}
```

Any other idea or a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `FrameworkElement` (which extends `UIElement`) instead of `UIElement`, in order to use `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties

Then create a static class which does some math `MouseUtils`

with those static fields

```
    private static double _dContainerTop;
    private static double _dContainerBottom;
    private static double _dContainerLeft;
    private static double _dContainerRight;
    private static double _dCursorTop;
    private static double _dCursorLeft;
    private static double _dCursorRight;
    private static double _dCursorBottom;
```

and those static methods

```
    private static void FindValues(FrameworkElement element, Visual rootVisual)
    {
        var containerTopLeft = container.TransformToAncestor(rootVisual).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        _dContainerTop = containerTopLeft.Y;
        _dContainerBottom = _dContainerTop + container.ActualHeight;
        _dContainerLeft = containerTopLeft.X;
        _dContainerRight = _dContainerLeft + container.ActualWidth;

    }
```

and

```
    public static bool IsElementUnderRectCursor(FrameworkElement element, Point startPoint, Point endPoint, Visual rootVisual)
    {
       _dCursorTop=Math.Min(startPoint.Y, endPoint.Y);
       _dCursorBottom=Math.Max(startPoint.Y, endPoint.Y);
       _dCursorLeft=Math.Min(startPoint.X, endPoint.X);
       _dCursorRight=Math.Max(startPoint.X, endPoint.X);

        FindValues(container, rootVisual);
        if (_dContainerTop < _dCursorTop|| _dCursorBottom< _dContainerBottom )
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (_dContainerLeft < _dCursorLeft|| _dContainerRight < _dCursorRight)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

`Rootvisual` being your window for example;

Then loop over `ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> wells` and call that function `IsElementUnderRectCursor`.

This is inspired from:
[Kinecting the Dots](http://geekswithblogs.net/mbcrump/archive/2011/07/04/kinecting-the-dots-adding-buttons-to-your-kinect-application.aspx)

Comment: Hi astreal, thanks for answer, it's working but the problem this approach injure the MVVM pattern:ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> wells in viewModel is the problem FrameWorkElement is a View.

Comment: You are right. 
But you should take a look here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083224/pushing-read-only-gui-properties-back-into-viewmodel)
And may be create a FramworkElementViewModel

Answer (score 0):

Astreal thanks again for your answer. It's done. I just moved the selection code from modelView to view. The selection done only in the UI.

```
private void SelectWells(RectangleGeometry selectionRectangle, FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
      var items = GetItemsControl(frameworkElement);

      foreach (var item in items.Items)
      {
        var viusalItem = (ContentPresenter)items.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);

        var wellControl = this.GetWellControl(viusalItem);

        var relativePoint = wellControl.TransformToAncestor(items).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        var controlRectangle =
          new RectangleGeometry(
            new Rect(relativePoint.X, relativePoint.Y, wellControl.ActualWidth, wellControl.ActualHeight));

        var intersectionGeometry = Geometry.Combine(
          selectionRectangle, controlRectangle, GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, null);

        if (intersectionGeometry.GetArea() > 0)
        {
          wellControl.Command.Execute(this);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

usefull link for u:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354853/WPF-Organization-Chart-Hierarchy-MVVM-Application

When an user clicks on a node in the tree we need to let the ViewModel node know that the selection has changed. We like to route the event as a command to the ViewModel