# Pushing ActualWidth/ActualHeight from a custom control to TemplateBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have set up a simple example to try to achieve a simple thing: exposing a dependency property in a custom control that exposes a ActualWidth/ActualHeight of a control within this custom control.

In order to attempt to achieve that I have:

customcontrol.cs

```
public class CustomControl : ContentControl
{
    static CustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RenderedWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "RenderedWidth", typeof (double), typeof (CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public double RenderedWidth
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(RenderedWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RenderedWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RenderedHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "RenderedHeight", typeof (double), typeof (CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public double RenderedHeight
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(RenderedHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RenderedHeightProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Custom_Control_Pushing_ActualWidth">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
                    <Grid local:SizeObserver.Observe="True"
                            local:SizeObserver.ObservedWidth="{Binding RenderedWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            local:SizeObserver.ObservedHeight="{Binding RenderedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

viewmodel.cs

```
class ViewModel
{
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public double Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set
        {
            width = value; 
            Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", value);
        }
    }

    public double Height
    {
        get { return height; }
        set
        {
            height = value;
            Console.WriteLine("Height: {0}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

mainwindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Custom_Control_Pushing_ActualWidth.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Custom_Control_Pushing_ActualWidth"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <local:CustomControl RenderedWidth="{Binding Width, Mode=OneWayToSource}" RenderedHeight="{Binding Height, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And I use SizeObserver from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1083733/276500).

However although I see the code in the dependency property being updated in the size observer, the bound viewmodel property's setter doesn't get set with the values. Something's wrong with my binding and I don't know what it is.

How can I correctly bind the DependencyProperty with the ViewModel's property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<Grid local:SizeObserver.Observe="True" 
      local:SizeObserver.ObservedWidth="{Binding RenderedWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
      local:SizeObserver.ObservedHeight="{Binding RenderedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
</Grid>
```

To this:

```
<Grid local:SizeObserver.Observe="True" 
      local:SizeObserver.ObservedWidth="{Binding RenderedWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
      local:SizeObserver.ObservedHeight="{Binding RenderedHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
</Grid>
```

So add `Mode=OneWayToSource` to the end of the binding.
This way the Width property in the ViewModel is properly updating for me.

The reason behind this is not entirely clear for me, but I think that the default binding mode of the `ObservedWidth` and `ObservedHeight` attached properties are OneWay. So they only update the target properties (`ObservedWidth, ObservedHeight`) when the source properties (`RenderedWidth, RenderedHeight`) change.

You want the exact opposite.
With the `OneWayToSource` modification the changes in the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties will nicely propagate up to your ViewModel.

Comment: Hey, thanks! This works! I could not identify the reason why to conclude `ObservedWidth` and `ObservedHeight` to be `OneWay` by default, through code reading, but again, I don't understand this WPF wiring much (will have to work on changing this :) ).