# How to map pixel location of stretched image to original image?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, scaletransform

My image is 20x20 pixels and when it's loaded it stretchs to fill the space of the grid which is WxH. When I click on the image I collect the mouse locations. Later I use them to draw the dots on the 20x20 image and save it to the file. But, because the image was stretched, I need to map the mouse location on WxH image to my original 20x20 image.

What is the proper way to do this in MVVM? 
My thoughts are:

1. Bind to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the image and then calculate the ratio between the original image and the stretched image.
2. Bind to the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` of `ScaleTransform` of the image. But, it always returns 1 for `ScaleX` and `ScaleY`.

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" Stretch="Fill">
         <Image.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX, Mode=OneWayToSource}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GetMouseLocationCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

**CODE**

```
public class VM
{
    public double ScaleX { get; set; }
    public double ScaleY { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When you do your calculations are you casting the ratios using decimal?

Comment: I don't quite understand how this is related to my question.

Comment: A point is an Int pair, Scale is a Double pair. If you are not casting correctly you will lose the decimal portion. Showing your code for "bind to scale" may allow others to see why you "always get 1". This is rather simple math

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I use Double.

Comment: Showing your code will probably help you get answers

Comment: What is the reason for downvote? What is not clear here?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the Image and then calculate the ratio between the original image and the stretched image.

Since these are read-only properties it requires some effort. Please refer to the following link for more information:

[Pushing read-only GUI properties back into ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083224/pushing-read-only-gui-properties-back-into-viewmodel)

These properties will be set when the `Image` is stretched. The `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties of the `ScaleTransform` will not.

Comment: @Why `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties of the `ScaleTransform` will not be set? When the image stretches, doesn't it change its scale?

Comment: No. At least not *that* scale.

Comment: Can you explain more or give a relevant article? I haven't found something that will explain what happenes when it stretches.

Comment: Did you even bother to read my answer? You should use the ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties...Your original question was "What is the proper way to do this in MVVM?" and this has been answered.