# How do I get the width of an element generated by Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, itemscontrol

I generate a list of elements with an `ObservableList` and an `ItemsControl`.
But I need to know the `ActualWidth` of the single controls with reference to the bound item in the list.

I need the `Width` to cut down my `Polyline` so that it is no longer than the `Canvas`

I tried a `OneWayToSource` and a `TwoWay` Binding back to the Item in the List with the `Width` Property. Always got NaN or 0.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="GraphLB" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <Border Padding="5, 0, 5, 0">
    <StackPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"/>
     <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Foreground}" BorderThickness="0.5">
      <Canvas MinHeight="40" MinWidth="100"
       Height="{Binding Height, Mode = TwoWay }"
       Width="{Binding Width, Mode = TwoWay }">
       <Polyline Points="{Binding Line}" Stroke="{Binding Foreground}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
      </Canvas>
     </Border>
    </StackPanel>
   </Border>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the Class for the Bound Objects

```
class GraphListObject : LabelListObject
{
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }

    private getProperty<PointCollection> getLine;
    public PointCollection Line { get { return GetLine(); } }
    internal getProperty<PointCollection> GetLine { get => getLine; set { getLine = value; } }
}
```

I expected that the `Width="{Binding Width, Mode = TwoWay }"` would set the Value in the Element of the List to the Width of the `Canvas` Element, but the actual output is 0.

Sadly the `Polyline` is drawn outside the borders:

[image]

Comment: The Canvas Width and Height are not set by layout. It's ActualWidth and ActualHeight instead. However, you can't bind these properties because they are readonly. See this for a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1083224/1136211. That said, doing this seems not to be necessary at all. The parts of the Polyline outside the Border's bounds aren't drawn anyway.

Comment: You mean outside the bounds of the inner Border? By the way, why do you have the outer Border at all? Seems redundant.

Comment: Sadly they are drawn https://prnt.sc/pvu6gj <- Screenshot
The outer Border is only for the Padding

Comment: Sorry, I won't follow external links. Outside the bounds of the inner Border or not?

Comment: For the Padding, you might as well set the Margin of the StackPanel.

Comment: But thats not the Problem. I just need to know how far i can draw the line.

Comment: Do you want to scale your line to be always within the canvas or do you want to ensure that the line doesn't appear outside the canvas? In second case, `ClipToBounds="true"` might help

Comment: That would fix a part of the problem, but I also want to cut the line at the beginning, so that the graph show the latest Information, this method cut on the wrong side.

Comment: `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`?