# ListView ItemsPanelTemplate with horizontal orientation, how to Identify ListViewItems on first row?

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, datatemplate, listviewitem

First of all I am working with **MVVM** / **WPF** / **.Net Framework 4.6.1**

I have a `ListView` configured with `ItemsPanelTemplate` in horizontal orientation that displays items from a `DataTemplate`. This setup allows me to fit as many items inside the *Width* of the `ListView` (the *witdth* size is the same from the Window), and behaves responsively when I resize the window.

So far everything is fine, now I just want to Identify what items are positioned on the first row, including when the window get resized and items inside the first row increase or decrease.

I merely want to accomplish this behavior because I would like to apply a different template style for those items (let's say a I bigger image or different text color).

[image]

Here below the XAML definition for the `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path = ItemsSource}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path = SelectedItem}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="180" Height="35">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="32" Width="32" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding IconPathName}" />
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Text="{Binding Name}" />

            </Grid> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

BTW: I already did a work around where I am getting the *Index* from each `ListViewItem` and calculating against the *Width* of the `Grid` inside the `DataTemplate` that is a fixed value of 180, but unfortunately it did not work as I expected since I had to use a `DependencyProperty` to bind the *ActualWidth* of the of the `ListView` to my ViewModel and did not responded very well when I resized the window.

I know I am looking for a very particular behavior, but if anyone has any suggestions about how to deal with this I would really appreciate. Any thoughts are welcome even if you think I should be using a different control, please detail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use ItemTemplateSelector to assign a different template to a specific item: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks but that would only work for one item at the time, if you see the screenshot attached I want to apply a different template for those items highlighted

Comment: I see, this logic should be based on the current layout of the panel. You mentioned that you are using a binding to Width, but it does not get updated. Have you tried ActualWidth instead? It should respond to UI changes.

Comment: Yes I did, actually I am implementing this SizeObserver class for it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1083733/1754814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't handle the layout in any view model. If you didn't extend `ListView` consider to use an attached behavior (raw example):

**ListBox.cs**

```
public class ListBox : DependencyObject
{
  #region IsAlternateFirstRowTemplateEnabled attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAlternateFirstRowTemplateEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsAlternateFirstRowTemplateEnabled", 
    typeof(bool), typeof(ListView), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), ListBox.OnIsEnabledChanged));

  public static void SetIsAlternateFirstRowTemplateEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value) => attachingElement.SetValue(ListBox.IsAlternateFirstRowTemplateEnabledProperty, value);

  public static bool GetIsAlternateFirstRowTemplateEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (bool)attachingElement.GetValue(ListBox.IsAlternateFirstRowTemplateEnabledProperty);

  #endregion

  private static void OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(attachingElement is System.Windows.Controls.ListBox listBox))
    {
      return;
    }

    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
      listBox.Loaded += ListBox.Initialize;
    }
    else
    {
      listBox.SizeChanged -= ListBox.OnListBoxSizeChanged;
    }
  }

  private static void Initialize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var listBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ListBox;
    listBox.Loaded -= ListBox.Initialize;

    // Check if items panel is WrapPanel
    if (!listBox.TryFindVisualChildElement(out WrapPanel panel))
    {
      return;
    }

    listBox.SizeChanged += ListBox.OnListBoxSizeChanged;
    ListBox.ApplyFirstRowDataTemplate(listBox);
  }

  private static void OnListBoxSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!e.WidthChanged)
    {
      return;
    }
    var listBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ListBox;
    ListBox.ApplyFirstRowDataTemplate(listBox);
  }

  private static void ApplyFirstRowDataTemplate(System.Windows.Controls.ListBox listBox)
  {
    double calculatedFirstRowWidth = 0;
    var firstRowDataTemplate = listBox.Resources["FirstRowDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
    foreach (FrameworkElement itemContainer in listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.Items
      .Select(listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem).Cast<FrameworkElement>())
    {
      calculatedFirstRowWidth += itemContainer.ActualWidth;
      if (itemContainer.TryFindVisualChildElement(out ContentPresenter contentPresenter))
      {
        if (calculatedFirstRowWidth > listBox.ActualWidth - listBox.Padding.Right - listBox.Padding.Left)
        {
          if (contentPresenter.ContentTemplate == firstRowDataTemplate)
          {
            // Restore the default template of previous first row items
            contentPresenter.ContentTemplate = listBox.ItemTemplate;
            continue;
          }

          break;
        }

        contentPresenter.ContentTemplate = firstRowDataTemplate;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Helper Extension Method**

```
/// <summary>
/// Traverses the visual tree towards the leafs until an element with a matching element type is found.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TChild">The type the visual child must match.</typeparam>
/// <param name="parent"></param>
/// <param name="resultElement"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool TryFindVisualChildElement<TChild>(this DependencyObject parent, out TChild resultElement)
  where TChild : DependencyObject
{
  resultElement = null;

  if (parent is Popup popup)
  {
    parent = popup.Child;
    if (parent == null)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);

    if (childElement is TChild child)
    {
      resultElement = child;
      return true;
    }

    if (childElement.TryFindVisualChildElement(out resultElement))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

**Usage**

```
<ListView x:Name="lv"  
          ListBox.IsAlternateFirstRowTemplateEnabled="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path = ItemsSource}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path = SelectedItem}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstRowDataTemplate">

            <!-- Draw a red border around first row items -->
            <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
                <Grid Width="180" Height="35">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="32" Width="32" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding IconPathName}" />
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Text="{Binding Name}" />

                </Grid> 
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="180" Height="35">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="32" Width="32" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding IconPathName}" />
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Text="{Binding Name}" />

            </Grid> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Remarks**
If the visual tree itself will not change for the first row, consider to add a second attached property to the `ListBox` class (e.g., `IsFirstRowItem`)  which you would set on the `ListBoxItems`. You can then use a `DataTrigger` to modify the control properties to change the appearance. This will very likely increase the performance too.

Comment: You totally got me, just what I needed, Thanks!