# How to make System.Windows.Forms.Panel fill the container in WPF when created in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm trying to hosting an exe on the WPF program by using WinfowsFormsHost and  System.Windows.Forms.Panel.Here is the code:

```
    public void AddPuttyPage(Process process)
        {
            var picPan = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel() { 
                Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
            };
            var winform = new WindowsFormsHost
            {
                Child = picPan,
                HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch
            };
            //Tabs are bind to the TabControl on a xaml
            Tabs.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Tab1", Content = winform });
            process.WaitForInputIdle();

            SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, picPan.Handle);
        }
```

I want the `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` fill the container so that the exe application fill the window. I set `Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill`,But it doesn't work,the Panel still has default size 100*200.

So what should I do to let the Panel fill it's container?(Panel's container is WindowsFormsHost,and WindowsFormsHost is the content of the TabItem, so I want the panel fill the tabPage in fact)

Comment: What is the size of `winform` control? In other words: is it wpf layout problem or winforms docking problem?

Comment: The size of the `WindowsFormsHost` is 0*0. I think it's a wpf layout problem.If I can get the height and width of the tabControl,I can define the WindowsFormsHost and Panel with  those. I try to get  height and width of the tabControl by dateBind `<TabControl Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}">` but they are 0.

Comment: Height and Width are the sizes you want to set initially. You have to use ActualHeight and ActualWidth when you want to manipulate other controls Height and Width.

Comment: But how to use  ActualHeight and ActualWidth? I don't know how to bind them to the ViewModel

Comment: [Hosting Win32 Content in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/hosting-win32-content-in-wpf) -- [Walkthrough: Host a Win32 Control in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-win32-control-in-wpf) -- [Layout Considerations for the WindowsFormsHost Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/layout-considerations-for-the-windowsformshost-element)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally，I did it by get the  ActualHeight and ActualWidth of the tabControl.ActualHeight and ActualWidth can be bind to viewModel by this solution :[the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083224/pushing-read-only-gui-properties-back-into-viewmodel) and then just init the Panel like this:

```
           var picPan = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel() { 
                Height = AcutalHeight,
                Width = AcutalWidth,
                Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
            };
```

finally use `ShowWindow(handle, SW_MAXIMIZE)`let the window fill the panel.