# MVVM WPF - How to bind the seleccted dates for a calendar control?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a calendar defined like so:

```
<Calendar Name="calendarA" SelectionMode="MultipleRange"/>
```

and a list box which displays the selected dates on the calendar:

```
<ListBox x:Name="dateListBox" ItemSource="{Binding ElementName=calendarA, Path=SelectedDates}" SelectionMode="Extended"/>
```

Now, this is all on the view, what I'd like to do is to somehow copy the selected dates either from the calendar or from the listbox to a property or ObservableCollection in my viewmodel, but I'm a little lost, how do I go about this? I didn't want to use code-behind

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3667609/1506454

Comment: If you don't "want to use code-behind", then implement an attached behaviour. The solution is roughly the same anyway. You need to add the selected dates to the source collection yourself.

Comment: Do `CalendarA` and `dateListBox` share the same datacontext/viewmodel? If so, can't you add an ObservableCollection<CalendarDate> property to the viewmodel and bind the `SelectedDates` and the `ItemsSource` to it?

Comment: @JürgenRöhr i don't think there's a CalendarDate data type,

Comment: @Slava According to your code a property of `SelectedDates` exists on the calendar. Take whatever class such a `SelectedDate` is made of and use it instead of `CalendarDate`.