# How to bind a read-only WPF control property (eg ActualWidth) so its value is accessible in the view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, actualwidth

I want to bind a read-only property of a control to my view model so that the value is available in the view model.

What is the best way of doing this?

For example I'd like to bind `ActualWidth` to a property in my view model.  The width value is generated by WPF using its layout logic so I can't generate this value in my view model and push it to the control property, as would normally be the case.  Instead I need to have WPF generate the value and push it to the view model.

I would just use `Mode=OneWayToSource`, but this doesn't work for read-only properties:

```
  <Border
      ...
      ActualWidth="{Binding MyDataModelWidth, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
      >
      ... child controls ...
  </Border>
```

The way I am doing it currently is to handle `SizeChanged` for the border and the code-behind plugs the value into the view model, but this doesn't feel quite right.

Has anyone already solved this problem?

UPDATE:
My question is effectively a duplicate of this one:
[Pushing read-only GUI properties back into ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083224/pushing-read-only-gui-properties-back-into-viewmodel)

Comment: Check these links http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0ed9ec9d-00b3-44ee-afa6-43396daf88dc/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083224/pushing-read-only-gui-properties-back-into-viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem as to why this is not working is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658170/onewaytosource-binding-from-readonly-property-in-xaml).

However, the given solution to create a throwing setter to pass the validation would not work in your case.

I think it's ok to call a method on the ViewModel. If that's the code behind part that bugs you, perhaps you can use interactivity to call a method based on an event trigger (SizeChanged).

Answer (score -1):

do you really need a binding for that?

```
    class MyVM
    {
        FrameworkElement _context;

        public MyVM(FrameworkElement context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public double Width
        {
            get { return _context.ActualWidth; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its an interesting idea, but the UI objects are generated from the view model objects, so I couldn't pass in the FrameworkElement via the constructor.  I suppose I could bind the view model object to the FrameworkElement later but this sounds like it would violate a WPF principle (I might be violating it anyway but at least in my current implementation the view model doesn't explicitly access the UI).

Comment: generally a ViewModel should not be aware (Read: Have references to) UI dependent code. In this case you would need references to WPF specific assemblies.