# Can I get object Width and Height by databinding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Object's width and height are binded to variables in modelview, so I can easly know size of the object. Unfortunetly they get `NotANumber` instead of actual value. I don't want to use standard object.Width and object.Height parameteres from code-behind, since it'd be complicated to access them from modelview. I've read something about ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties, but they are not available in my Visual Studio 2010. What should I do?

XAML:

```
<ListView Width="{Binding wdth, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
          Height="{Binding hght, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

Code-behind:

```
public class modelview
{
    public double wdth {get;set;}
    public double hght {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Probably this answer can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083224/pushing-read-only-gui-properties-back-into-viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to get the ActualWidth and ActualHeight
they are not availble throw binding attatched property is way, see the answer links in :
[How to bind a read-only WPF control property (eg ActualWidth) so its value is accessible in the view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438412/how-to-bind-a-read-only-wpf-control-property-eg-actualwidth-so-its-value-is-ac)

Comment: Have you tried compiling this code? `ActualHeight` is a read-only DP and hence can't be bind to.