# Why I cannot bind a DependencyProperty to an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, databound

I have a usercontrol done by myself that has a dependency property that is a collection:

```
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey VerticalLinesPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("VerticalLines", typeof(VerticalLineCollection), typeof(DailyChart), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new VerticalLineCollection()));
    public static DependencyProperty VerticalLinesProperty = VerticalLinesPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;


    public VerticalLineCollection VerticalLines
    {
        get
        {
            return (VerticalLineCollection)base.GetValue(VerticalLinesProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(VerticalLinesProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

I was filling this collection from XAML directly when a Window was using the control with code like:

```
<chart:DailyChart.VerticalLines>
    <VerticalLine ... ... ... />
</chart:DailyChart.VerticalLines>
```

Now, I removed this fixed initialization from XAML and I want to bind the collection to a property of the ViewModel but I get the error:

```
Error   1   'VerticalLines' property cannot be data-bound.
Parameter name: dp
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?" - show the Source property and the binding in Xaml .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XAML example, the parser sees that the `VerticalLineCollection` type implements `IList` and hence for each specified `VerticalLine` will create a `VerticalLine` object and then call `Add` on the collection itself.

However, when you attempt to bind the collection, the semantics become "assign a new collection to the `VerticalLines` property", which can't be done since this is a read-only dependency property. The setter on your property really should be marked as private, and in doing so you will get a compile-time error instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, to be able to bind the property I need to declare it as a normal read/write property right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because of [(True read-only dependency property)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/658683/1197605).

As you have read only property you may change it to

```
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey VerticalLinesPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.Register("VerticalLines", typeof(VerticalLineCollection), typeof(DailyChart), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new VerticalLineCollection()));
        public static DependencyProperty VerticalLinesProperty = VerticalLinesPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
```

Reflector gives the answer:

```
    internal static BindingExpression CreateBindingExpression(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, Binding binding, BindingExpressionBase parent)
    {
        FrameworkPropertyMetadata fwMetaData = dp.GetMetadata(d.DependencyObjectType) as FrameworkPropertyMetadata;
        if (((fwMetaData != null) && !fwMetaData.IsDataBindingAllowed) || dp.ReadOnly)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(System.Windows.SR.Get(System.Windows.SRID.PropertyNotBindable, new object[] { dp.Name }), "dp");
        }
        ....
```

Hope this will work