# Set ViewModel property when a TextBox is focused

Tags: wpf, mvvm, focus

I have a MVVM application and I want to keep track of the focused element in my ViewModel.

I would like to set ViewModel property when a TextBox is focused.
I would like to have something like this

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding P1}">
    <TextBox.Style>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
         <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="{Binding P1Selected}" Value="True"/>
           </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
 </TextBox>
```

where P1 and P1Selected are viewModel properties.
Of course this code does not work. I wrote it just to give the idea..

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Sorry, my answer was wrong.
Please see [OneWayToSource binding from readonly property in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7227295/754357).

Comment: You cannot bind IsFocused. Because it is a readonly property.

Comment: You still cannot do that. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658170/onewaytosource-binding-from-readonly-property-in-xaml

Comment: "'IsFocused' property is read-only and cannot be set from markup." Both for OneWay and for OneWayToSource

Comment: I have solved the problem thanks to @Amit link and in particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7227295/754357)