# One way to source binding is not being set

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm attempting to bind to a readonly property on a third party control (so no control over the implementation of the property). As I understand, I need to do this as a onewaytosource binding type, and also need to do it in code.

I have the following code to set the binding:

```
            Binding svBinding = new Binding();
        svBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("SurfaceScrollViewer");
        svBinding.Source = DataContext;
        svBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
        Ds.SetBinding(DiagramSurface.ScrollViewerProperty, svBinding);
```

And my property implementation on the view model:

```
public DiagramScrollViewer SurfaceScrollViewer
    {
        get
        {
            return surfaceScrollViewer;
        }
        set
        {
            surfaceScrollViewer = value;
        }
    }

    private DiagramScrollViewer surfaceScrollViewer;
```

I can access other properties in the same data context by code, but for some reason, I cannot  get this property to bind. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: do you get an error in the output window?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because it is a bug of wpf. Take a look of this http://meleak.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/onewaytosource-binding-for-readonly-dependency-property/

Answer (score 0):

Hi I misunderstood your question Sorry. It is a kind of bug in wpf for binding ReadOnly properties with  OneWayToSource BindingMode you can get exact answer for this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658170/onewaytosource-binding-from-readonly-property-in-xaml)

Comment: This won't help because the Target is readonly. The idea is to have the property in the viewmodel updated when the property is changed. Not the other way around.