# How to set a viewmodel property when Property Trigger fires

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I have a ListView with a View Model. The ItemsSource is a collection of objects in the View Model. A property exists on the View Model for some flag, IsFlagOn. I want to set that property in the View Model to True when the ListViewItem detects a IsMouseOver. Other UI elements are then bound to this same property so that the view changes as MouseOver is toggled.

How would I accomplish this in XAML?

I would imagine something like this (but this breaks):

```
<Style> <!-- on the ListViewItem -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="DataContext.IsFlagOn" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

UPDATE:

The error is

> Cannot resolve the Style Property 'IsFlagOn'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Property.

UPDATE(2):

Here's a bit more of the existing XAML (following). You can see that the ListView is bound with a property of the VM, `AllItems`. Important to note that each item in the list is a VM, where each column is bound. So is the ItemContainerStyle binding against the ListView VM or the Item VM?

```
<ListView Itemssource="{Binding AllItems}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style> <!-- on the ListViewItem -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="DataContext.IsFlagOn" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <!-- ... -->
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: `but this breaks` with what exception? Is `IsFlagOn` a dependency property?

Comment: Error is "Type DataContext is not found". View model is plain class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so `IsFlagOn` is not a dependency property.

Comment: OK, so what is the actual exception?

Comment: Are you applying this style on the ListView, and yet want the "IsMouseOver" property change to be detected for each individual ListViewItem? The way I see it, this will react whenever the mouse is over the ListView itself, not any particular ListViewItem. Is this what you really want?

Comment: @Samir see update. It's a style on ListViewItem.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange see updated comment

Comment: is `IsFlagOn` a property belonging to the VM or does it belong to each item in your collection? If it's the VM that's prolly the error, Use a RelativeSource Binding with TargetType as ListView to get to the right scope and then you should be able to find the property.

Comment: @Viv, I updated my question with more of the XAML. The property belongs to each item in the collection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty much what `OneWayToSource` binding mode was made for - being able to just update the view model from the view. However, since `IsMouseOver` is a read-only property, you *won't* be able to do this (due to a bug in WPF):

```
<Setter Property="IsMouseOver" Value="{Binding Path=IsFlagOn, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

There are ways to get around it though. Some of them are described here: [OneWayToSource binding from readonly property in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/658170/389966)