# Allow only OneWayToSource binding mode

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have `EntitiesUserControl` responsible for `EntitiesCount` dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EntitiesCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(EntitiesCount),
    typeof(int),
    typeof(EntitiesUserControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public int EntitiesCount
{
    get { return (int)this.GetValue(EntitiesCountProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(EntitiesCountProperty, value); }
}
```

Another (primary) control include `EntitiesUserControl` and read it property through binding:

```
<controls:EntitiesUserControl EntitiesCount="{Binding CountOfEntities, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

`CountOfEntities` property in view model just store and process changing of count value:

```
private int countOfEntities;
public int CountOfEntities
{
    protected get { return this.countOfEntities; }
    set
    {
        this.countOfEntities = value;
        // Custom logic with new value...
    }
}
```

I need `EntitiesCount` property of `EntitiesUserControl` to be **read-only** (primary control must not change it, just read) and it works this way only because `Mode=OneWayToSource` declared explicitly. But if declare `TwoWay` mode or don't explicitly declare mode, then `EntitiesCount` could be rewritten from outside (at least right after binding initialization, because it happens **after** default dependency property value assigned).

I can't do 'legal' read-only dependency property due to binding limitations (best described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/658683/5177728)), so I need to prevent bindings with mode other than `OneWayToSource`. It would be best to have some *OnlyOneWayToSource* flag like `BindsTwoWayByDefault` value in [`FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration...

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what's wrong with using `Mode=OneWayToSource`. The only problem is that you have to type that out or what? Sorry I don't quite grok the problem here. I'll share a hacky way to achieve only `OneWayToSource` binding, but not sure that that's what you need.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi The problem is not that I *have to* type, the problem is just the other way - that I *may not* type, and nothing will tell me that I going to use property the way that it not supposed to be used. As an analogy - you can't compile program if you write code that assign value to read-only property.

Comment: @Sam FWIW I agree with you and would love to see an elegant solution to this also. But nothing about XAML or WPF seems to espouse the safety philosophy you are referring to :(

Answer (score 3):

It's a „bit” hacky, but you can create a `Binding`-derived class and use that instead of `Binding`:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(OneWayToSourceBinding))]
public class OneWayToSourceBinding : Binding
{
    public OneWayToSourceBinding()
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
    }

    public OneWayToSourceBinding(string path) : base(path)
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
    }

    public new BindingMode Mode
    {
        get { return BindingMode.OneWayToSource; }
        set
        {
            if (value == BindingMode.OneWayToSource)
            {
                base.Mode = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<controls:EntitiesUserControl EntitiesCount="{local:OneWayToSourceBinding CountOfEntities}" />
```

The namespace mapping `local` might be something else for you.

This `OneWayToSourceBinding` sets the `Mode` to `OneWayToSource` and prevents setting it to anything else.

Comment: Thanks for example, it is enough interesting, at least I have newer used bindings this way... That is not exactly what I need, but it somewhat relative: just like your custom binding prevent using any mode other than 'OneWayToSource', I need dependency property to prevent binding to itself any binding other than your custom binding, or any standart binding with mode other than 'OneWayToSource'.