# MSDN documentation on bindability of TreeView.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, selecteditem

It seems that for a `TreeView`, the property `SelectedItem` cannot be used for binding. I am trying to understand how this can be consistent with the MSDN documentation.

On https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditem.aspx it says about the `Treeview.SelectedItem` property:

> ```
> [BindableAttribute(true)]
> public object SelectedItem { get; }
> ```

Then, this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.bindableattribute.aspx says under "Remarks":

> If a property has been marked with the `BindableAttribute` set to `true`,
>   then a property change notification should be raised for that
>   property. This means that if the `Bindable` property is `Yes`, then
>   two-way data binding is supported. If `Bindable` is `No`, you can still
>   bind to the property, but it should not be shown in the default set of
>   properties to bind to, because it might or might not raise a property
>   change notification.

I read it as "If your property has `BindableAttribute` set to `true`, you can bind to it; no matter which value is set to `Bindable`." `Bindable` is not listed in the `[...]` part for `SelectedItem`, which I assume means that `Bindable` is set to `No`.

**So according to the documentation, binding to `SelectedItem` should work, right?** Or am I misunderstanding something? If yes, what?

<s>If I write</s>

```
<TreeView SelectedItem="{Binding foo, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

it says "The `SelectedItem` property does not have an accessible setter." (Original: "Die `SelectedItem`-Eigenschaft" verfügt über kein Setter-Objekt, auf das zugegriffen werden kann.)

But now I'm confused again - I told it to only use `OneWayToSource` binding, meaning that changes of `SelectedItem` reflect in `foo`, but not the other way around. So **why does it even care about the setter?** see [OneWayToSource binding from readonly property in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/658170/5333340) , [Pushing read-only GUI properties back into ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1083224/5333340)

Answer (score 0):

SelectedItem is only the reference to the item currently selected. You need to define the property of SelectedItemPath and DisplayMemberPath and then bind TreeView to collection via ItemsSource.
Like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" />
```

DisplayMemberPath - which property will be shown on GUI control (ie. Name of customer)
SelectedValuePath - which property will be value of selected item (usually ID)

Edit: Just wanted to point to the "get" only property in SelectedItem