# WPF/XAML – Binding of WindowChrome.CaptionHeight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window-chrome

*Theme/Generic.xaml* of my **WPF Custom Control** *MyBaseWindow* looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyBaseWindowPath:MyBaseWindow}">
        …
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=HeaderPanel}"
                              GlassFrameThickness="0"
                              CornerRadius="0" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyBaseWindowPath:MyBaseWindow}">
                    …
                    <DockPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel">
                    …
                    </DockPanel>
                    …
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would like to bind `ActualHeight` property of **HeaderPanel element** within `ControlTemplate`. Is it possible?

---

Another solution is use fixed height for `WindowChrome.CaptionHeight` and `HeaderPanel.Height`, but I prefer binding to exact height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ActualHeight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a `DependencyProperty` or an `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so you can't bind directly to it and expect more than a one-time read.  You can set a trigger on it in a style.

Work-around includes:

- Creating a property in your class (view side) that is either a `DependencyProperty` or an `INotifyPropertyChanged` property.
- Registering for the `SizeChanged` event on the element you want to know the `AbsoluteHeight` on.
- In the handler for the event, update the property you created.

A fancier implementation would use attached dependency properties that essentially do the same thing, but they would be a bit more general purpose.

Comment: `ActualHeight` **is** a DependencyProperty. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheightproperty(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Vlad, I stand corrected, but for whatever reason you still can't do a OneWayToSource binding to let your ViewModel know how big something is on screen--necessary for fancy meters and such.

Comment: I assume that the problem is following: `ActualHeight` is a read-only property, so Binding erroneously refuses to be created even with OneWayToSource mode. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7227295/276994

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, my solution without binding was to assign a x:Name to the WindowChrome and change `CaptionHeight` value in `Window_SizeChanged` event:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SessionWindowChrome.CaptionHeight = ActualHeight
       - SessionWindowChrome.ResizeBorderThickness.Top 
       - SessionWindowChrome.ResizeBorderThickness.Bottom;    
}
```

Take in account that i use `ResizeBorderThickness` variables too...