# WPF - binding to read-only attached property. Need solution clarification

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, attached-properties

I have tried to bind my view model property to Validation.HasErrors attached property of a text box (which is read-only). I found a good working solution in this answer by Johan Larsson: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39392158
But I am not an expert on WPF, so I have a hard time understanding how and why it works. I am really puzzled because I don't know all the implicit rules of WPF and XAML engines. I understand the basics of attached properties, binding, and XAML markup, but I don't understand how it comes together in the end.
Can someone clarify what is happening here? Here is the code from the solution:

```
public static class OneWayToSource
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Bindings",
        typeof(OneWayToSourceBindings),
        typeof(OneWayToSource),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(OneWayToSourceBindings), OnBinidngsChanged));

    public static void SetBindings(this FrameworkElement element, OneWayToSourceBindings value)
    {
        element.SetValue(BindingsProperty, value);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForChildren(IncludeDescendants = false)]
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(FrameworkElement))]
    public static OneWayToSourceBindings GetBindings(this FrameworkElement element)
    {
        return (OneWayToSourceBindings)element.GetValue(BindingsProperty);
    }

    private static void OnBinidngsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((OneWayToSourceBindings)e.OldValue)?.ClearValue(OneWayToSourceBindings.ElementProperty);
        ((OneWayToSourceBindings)e.NewValue)?.SetValue(OneWayToSourceBindings.ElementProperty, d);
    }
}

public class OneWayToSourceBindings : FrameworkElement
{
    private static readonly PropertyPath DataContextPath = new PropertyPath(nameof(DataContext));
    private static readonly PropertyPath HasErrorPath = new PropertyPath($"({typeof(Validation).Name}.{Validation.HasErrorProperty.Name})");
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(HasError),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(OneWayToSourceBindings),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    internal static readonly DependencyProperty ElementProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Element",
        typeof(UIElement),
        typeof(OneWayToSourceBindings),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(UIElement), OnElementChanged));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProxyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "HasErrorProxy",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(OneWayToSourceBindings),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnHasErrorProxyChanged));

    public bool HasError
    {
        get { return (bool)this.GetValue(HasErrorProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(HasErrorProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnHasErrorProxyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.SetCurrentValue(HasErrorProperty, e.NewValue);
    }

    private static void OnElementChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == null)
        {
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(d, DataContextProperty);
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(d, HasErrorProxyProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            var dataContextBinding = new Binding
                                         {
                                             Path = DataContextPath,
                                             Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                                             Source = e.NewValue
                                         };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(d, DataContextProperty, dataContextBinding);

            var hasErrorBinding = new Binding
                                      {
                                          Path = HasErrorPath,
                                          Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                                          Source = e.NewValue
                                      };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(d, HasErrorProxyProperty, hasErrorBinding);
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml part:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueInVM, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <local:OneWayToSource.Bindings>
            <local:OneWayToSourceBindings HasError="{Binding ValueInVM}" />
        </local:OneWayToSource.Bindings>
    </TextBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ValueInVM, Mode=OneWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OneWayToSource binding from readonly property in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658170/onewaytosource-binding-from-readonly-property-in-xaml)

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/658170) more helpful.  The most upvoted answer (but not the *accepted* answer...) has an associated [blog post](https://meleak.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/onewaytosource-binding-for-readonly-dependency-property/) that goes over the details a bit more.

That blog post includes `PushBinding` and `PushBindingManager` - the two main pieces you need to get all this working well (plus a couple other little classes, but they're no biggie).

These are a bit more well done (in my opinion) than the code you referenced in your post.  It's what I use in my own code (or, at least, what I derived mine from).

---

First, the most crucial point to consider:

**Read-only dependency properties do not have public property setters.**  Looking at the example `FishCount` property in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/read-only-dependency-properties?view=netdesktop-6.0#creating-custom-read-only-dependency-properties):

```
    internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey FishCountPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
          name: "FishCount",
          propertyType: typeof(int),
          ownerType: typeof(Aquarium),
          typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    // Declare a public get accessor.
    public int FishCount =>
        (int)GetValue(FishCountPropertyKey.DependencyProperty);
```

You can see that there's only a public *getter* - no *setter*.  Now, let's add to this, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerattachedreadonly?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for read-only *attached* properties states (emphasis mine)

> Read-only attached properties are a rare scenario, because the primary scenario for an attached property is its use in XAML. Without a public setter, an attached property cannot be set in **XAML syntax.**

---

**So - if we can't set it in XAML - maybe we can set it in C#.**

That's what the code that you're referencing does.

The general approach to this problem is to:

- Provide an approach (usually an attached property) that supports binding *via XAML* (i.e., *read-write* properties)
- Hook into  the above so that when a change is made, some logic is performed in C# that will:

  - Create a `OneWay` binding between the *read-only* target property (e.g., `Validation.HasErrors`) and an implementation-specific property (let's call it `ListenerProperty`)
  - Subscribe to the property changed event for `ListenerProperty`.
  - When `ListenerProperty` changes, update a second implementation-specific property, say... `MirrorProperty` to the same value.
  - Create a `OneWayToSource` binding between `MirrorProperty` and your view model to push the value back to your view model

I've made an illustration of how `PushBinding` works (the example from the blog post I linked)

[image: Illustration of how PushBinding works]